# Can EWS Impersonation be used with Office365 Email Account service provider?

Tags: office365, exchangewebservices, ews-managed-api

We're building a service that is initially heavy on message download.  We're trying to find all the tricks to increase our message download throughput.

Came across this post

> Standard recommended: The industrial-strength work-around which works
>   well is to use a pool of accounts in a round-robin queue for doing the
>   EWS calls using EWS Impersonation.  By doing this the server will see
>   the same account having a lesser load.  This is the usual recommended
>   approach and needs to be strongly looked at – especially when the
>   other suggestions above don't work. It is the most scalable and will
>   handle load from little to massive huge.  Small companies all the way
>   up to the largest companies use this approach.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdav_101/2018/03/20/ews-serverbusyexception-the-server-is-too-busy-for-you/

We believe that we would require us to ask each user to grant us the ability to perform EWS impersonation on their behalf and this was not part of the standard permissions bundle.  Is this true?

Unless it's a single click, it's basically a non-starter from a business point of view.

If so, any other suggestions to improve message download performance?

Answer (score 0):

Using exchange management shell,you can configure & grant [ApplicationImpersonation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn722376(v=exchg.150).aspx) role without prompting users.

High volume applications will need to use multiple impersonation accounts or adjust [throttling policies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj945066(v=exchg.150).aspx) when you start seeing ServerBusyExceptions.

In terms of performance - it depends. Only pull properties you need.  If you are pulling all mail items and timing is not a concern - consider [push\pull notifications](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn458791(v=exchg.150).aspx).  If you need to be as close to real-time as possible, look into [streaming notifications](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdav_101/2015/11/17/ews-streaming-notifications-with-exchange-2013/).

Comment: To clarify. We will be a service provider.  So, we won't be able to keep a PowerShell window open and watch as people create accounts.  Account creation will be 24/7 and users will NOT be under our control.  With that said, can we grant ApplicationImpersonation from C# code?  if so that will help.  

Note, we do already see ServerBusyExceptions and do already do retry and backoff of suggested amount of time.  Also, we're only having issues during block message download.

Comment: As a service provider, do you have a a service account used as an impersonation account within the target user's azure domain?  If so, then just granting ApplicationImpersonation one time to that account will work for new accounts as they are added to the domain.

Comment: Since these are people that we have no relationship with, we do NOT have an Azure account in the users azure domain.

Comment: It shounds like this entire technique is geared to work inside a company. ?

Comment: The impersonation model works in both on-premises and o365 installs - The later would seem to provide some hurdles for service provider operating outside the user's organization.  Given the sensitive nature of email, it's understandable. Perhaps you could try to wrap up the powershell to impersonate and stick it behind a single button.  
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kebab/2014/04/28/executing-powershell-scripts-from-c/

Comment: If there is a powershell command, there might be a c# one also?

Comment: Pretty sure there is no native c# api. Your option seems to be to cobble together the [impersonation powershell](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn722376(v=exchg.150).aspx) with a [.net powershell wrapper](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kebab/2014/04/28/executing-powershell-scripts-from-c/)